# WSO2 DSS : Rest call to database with null values

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to call a service in the DSS with this configuration :

```
<query id="getAllPerformancesQuery" useConfig="lta_catalogue">
    <sql>select idperformance, name, description from performance</sql>
    <result element="performances" rowName="performance">
        <element column="idperformance" name="idperformance" xsdType="integer"/>
        <element column="name" name="name" xsdType="string"/>
        <element column="description" name="description" xsdType="string"/>
    </result>
</query>
<resource method="GET" path="performances">
    <call-query href="getAllPerformancesQuery"/>
</resource>
```

With a soap call the dss responds well :

```
<performances xmlns="com.lta.catalog.CatalogDSS">
    <performance>
        <idperformance>1</idperformance>
        <name>Introduction</name>
        <description xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    </performance>
</performances>
```

But with a rest call, the null value in the column description respond :

```
{"Fault":{"faultcode":"soapenv:Server","faultstring":"Error while writing to the output stream using JsonWriter","detail":""}}
```

with this exception in the log :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dangling name: description
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.close(JsonWriter.java:302)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.endObject(JsonWriter.java:277)
    at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.GsonXMLStreamWriter.writeEndElement(GsonXMLStreamWriter.java:394)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.XMLWriterHelper.endElement(XMLWriterHelper.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.Query.writeResultEntry(Query.java:400)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processNormalQuery(SQLQuery.java:857)
    ... 54 more
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Editing the respository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml and changing the right messagebuilder and formatter

```
    <messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                  class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/>
<!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.json.gson.JsonFormatter" /-->


<messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONOMBuilder"/>
<!--messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.json.gson.JsonBuilder" /-->
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in the DSS 3.2.2 release. The related JIRA can be found from [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15046)